Mesh's empty space not reachable in hydroelastic grasping maybe due to mesh margin

As you can see from this picture above the empty space of the Bowl is not reachable.
I tried using the latest Drake v1.34 version and setting the mesh margin accordingly for the responsible sdf-file (I have used the same .obj file for collision and visual) for my hydroelastic grasping experiments:
        <drake:proximity_properties>
          <drake:compliant_hydroelastic/>
          <drake:hydroelastic_modulus>1e7</drake:hydroelastic_modulus>
          <drake:mu_dynamic>0.3</drake:mu_dynamic>
          <drake:mu_static>0.3</drake:mu_static>
          <drake:hunt_crossley_dissipation>50.0</drake:hunt_crossley_dissipation>
          <drake:hydroelastic_margin>1e-4</drake:hydroelastic_margin>
          <drake:mesh_resolution_hint>1e-4</drake:mesh_resolution_hint>
        </drake:proximity_properties>

with no change.
The code I am using for my experiment setup is this.
Reading the Margin for Hydroelastic Contact documentation I stumbled upon this:

It's worth noting that only in a few cases are we truly producing an
offset surface (spheres and capsules). For other convex primitives we
approximate the offset surface of a shape with a larger shape of the
same type. Non-convex shapes require additional consideration and are
discussed in further detail in Non-Convex Geometries.

The section about Non-Convex Geometries unwritten at the time of writing. I am guessing that we may also approximate the offset surface with a primitive shape here?
Can I do something about it?
You can replicate the shown scenario by executing my code on my branch with this exact object and gripper pose:

git clone git@github.com:hedaniel7/drake.git
cd drake
git checkout Drakev1.34.0WithIssue19842Mods
git checkout 95627b3bddce710b7ac8d7fff65a5f48148682f5
bazel run //examples/simple_gripper:robotiq_140_uogp_2024 -- --position=-0.021054,0.132327,0.186262 --orientation=0.686237,0.703709,-0.078858,0.166295 --gripper_opening=0.008972 --manual_correction=0.0 --table_correction=-0.044659 --NoHeightCorrection --uogp_object=Bowl

Thank you in advance

This is unlikely caused by the margin. Looks like your are feeding in an obj as a compliant hydro geometry and its convex hull is being used as the collision geometry.

To enable compliant hydro for a mesh without resorting to its convex hull, you need to supply a volume mesh in a vtk format. An alternative is to model the bowl as a rigid hydro geometry. In that case, the original surface mesh from the obj will be used and no convex hull will be created.

Thank you for your fast reply.
I changed the bowl to rigid hydro geometry in the .sdf file. It still has the same problem.

I doubt that the "exact same" problem is occuring. If you changed the bowl to rigid hydroelastic and the apparent problem (i.e. the bowl still behaves as its convex hull as far as contact is concerned) persists, it's likely that your other geometry in contact (i.e. the gripper) is also modeled with rigid hydro. If that's the case, the contact force arrows would be green instead of red and blue. Can you confirm if that's the case?

Keep in mind that one of the drawbacks of modeling with rigid hydro is that there's no such thing as rigid hydro vs. rigid hydro contact; when that happens, we fallback to point contact, which also uses the convex hull of non-convex meshes.

Thank you very much!
The issue got resolved. It was exactly like you described. I changed the gripper's fingerpads to compliant hydroelastic and it works now.
